# Obtener datos de usuario logueado con codeigniter y mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto en codeigniter, y tengo una duda con el login de la aplicación, lo que necesito es obtener los datos del usuario logueado (con su RUT y Contraseña) para mostrarlos en la pagina de inicio.
El controlador es el siguiente:

```
public function Index(){
    $usu_rut = $this->session->userdata('usu_rut');
            switch ($this->session->userdata('per_nombre')) {
        case '':
    $data['titulo']="Inicio de Sesión";
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
            break;
        case 'Administrador':
            redirect(base_url().'administrador');
            break;
        case 'Postulante':
            redirect(base_url().'postulante');
            break;
        case 'Evaluador':
            redirect(base_url().'evaluador');
            break;
        default:
    $data['titulo']="Inicio de Sesión";
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
            break;
    }

}      

public function validar(){
    $datos = array(
                    'USU_RUT'   =>  $this->input->post('USU_RUT'),
                    'USU_PASS'  =>  md5($this->input->post('USU_PASS'))
                    );
    $data = $this->m_login->get_data($datos['USU_RUT'],$datos['USU_PASS']);
            if ($data) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('usu_rut',$data['USU_RUT']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('usu_nombre1',$data['USU_NOMBRE1']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('per_nombre',$data['PER_NOMBRE']);
            $this->index();
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_error', 'Error, intente nuevamente');
            $data['titulo']="Inicio de Sesión";
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        }
}
```

El modelo es el siguiente:

```
public function get_data($USU_RUT,$USU_PASS){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('usuario_usu');
    $this->db->where('USU_RUT', $USU_RUT);
    $this->db->where('USU_PASS', $USU_PASS);
    $this->db->join('perfiles_per', 'perfiles_per.PER_ID = usuario_usu.PER_ID');
    if ($query=$this->db->get()) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Al hacer la consulta a la bd obtiene el perfil de usuario, y compara el perfil con la función switch y lo redirije a otro controlador con sus permisos para el perfil, este el controlador del administrador:

```
public function Index(){;
    $data['titulo'] = "Pagina Principal";
    $this->load->view('plantillas/Header',$data);
    $this->load->view('inicio');
}
```

Cualquier ayuda la agradezco.

Comment: Y qué es lo que no te está resultando? No llegan datos a la vista?

Comment: Exacto, no se como pasar los valores obtenidos al controlador que me carga la vista.